# how I can get instance of a form in runtime?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In my application I need show a data in multiple forms that these forms exactly have same VCLs, events and procedures, because the amounts of these forms are depending on to my application, So I can't create all of them in design-time.

Or How can I make a copy of a form multiple times in run-time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your form is declared as TForm2, you can easily create say 10 instances of it like this:

```
var 
  myForms: TArray<TForm2>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(myForms, 10);
  for I:=0 to 9 do begin
    myForms[I] := TForm2.Create(Application);  // Application will free the forms on exit
    myForms[I].Show;
  end;
end;
```

If you don't need to access the form instances you can omit the array completely and write:

```
var 
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I:=0 to 9 do begin
    TForm2.Create(Application).Show;  // Application will free the forms on exit
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

to create undetermined number of forms you can use this code ..

```
private
   MyForm: array of TForm;

procedure TForm1.CreateForms(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(MyForm, Length(MyForm) + 1);
  MyForm[Length(MyForm) - 1] := TForm1.Create(Self);
  MyForm[Length(MyForm) - 1].Name := 'Form' + IntToStr(Length(MyForm));
  MyForm[Length(MyForm) - 1].Caption := 'Form' + IntToStr(Length(MyForm));
  MyForm[Length(MyForm) - 1].Show;
end;
```

Comment: You should use `high(MyForm)` instead of `Length(MyForm) - 1`. It yields the exact same value but reads better.